# How to avoid overflow error with recursive entities [Hibernate 5, MySQL 8]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

my problem consist in how to fetch a recursive table in a entity's field with out getting an "Exception occurred in target VM: java.lang.StackOverflowError"

I have an Activity class that realize a recursive table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activities")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "activity_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Activity parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Activity> childs;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and a Permission class that has a many to many relations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions")
public class Permission {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "permission_id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "permission_activity", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id"))
    private Set<Activity> activities;

}
```

I'm using a JpaRepository abstraction to load database's data, when i try to access to activities filed it goes to OverFlow error.
It is another way to directly set a named query when it comes to retrieve tha activities field?

Comment: Look at here if it helps: https://www.viralpatel.net/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/

Comment: I did as it is in the blog link ... so it doesn't help me. thanks.